# Pytest throws an argument error when running a test with predefined arguments vai argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, pytest

Sorry, this is long.  We have created many Selenium test scripts before running into pytest.  Each test imports a framework we created; that framework has an argument parser set up similar to the following:

```
# Methods class

from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import argparse

config = SafeConfigParser()
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-d", "--logdirectory", help="help for directory")
parser.add_argument("-b", "--browser", help="help for browser")
parser.add_argument("--debug", help="help for debug")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Each test imports that class:

```
from TestMethods import Methods

app = "specific tool to test"
test = Methods(app)
print "just doing something"
```

Let's pretend that that's all that is happening.  To my understanding, in order for pytest to work, you need to have your tests in a method, so:

```
from TestMethods import Methods

@pytest.mark.run
def test_test1():
    app = "specific tool to test"
    test = Methods(app)
    print "just doing something"
```

Now to run this, I can just call:

```
py.test
```

and that will technically work.  However, if I want to specify the test:

```
py.test test_script_name.py
```

or to look only for methods marked run:

```
py.test test_script_name.py -m run
```

or do anything that involves adding arguments:

```
py.test test_script_name.py -d logname
```

it throws an argument error such as:

```
---------------------------- Captured stderr call ----------------------
usage: py.test [-h] [-d LOGDIRECTORY] [-b {firefox,chrome,ie}] [--debug]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: test_script_name.py
```

I assume this is happening because the argparse doesn't allow arguments other than the ones I specified in the framework.  How do I make it so the tests don't break when I send in arguments? I'd prefer to keep using argparse, but if it's not possible, then I could probably accept other ideas.

EDIT:

I'm pretty sure that I essentially just want py.test to allow additional arguments when calling a test from the command line.  In this case, I want to be able to send in -d and -b; the test will be able to read those fine, I just need py.test to allow it.  Something else to note is that argparse allows this command:

```
parser.parse_known_args()
```

which makes it just ignore any arguments that aren't specified using add_argument.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I can offer an answer that does not use `argparse`, but the `pytest_addoption` hook - see also http://pytest.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/example/simple.html . With this you can pass options (eg. cmdopt) to py.test and then run as

`py.test --debug=<whatever> test_script_name.py`

Quoting from the linked example, your `conftest.py` should contain:

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
parser.addoption("--debug", help="help for debug")
```

You can then pass the value of the option (or all options) to test function, as in this example:

```
# content of test_test1.py
def test_test1(pytestconfig):
    debug = pytestconfig.option.debug # pass a single option
    all_options = pytestconfig.option # pass all options
    assert(False)
```

Or you can use the option in a fixture (this was my problem). In this case, you can obtain the value from the request object. I think you can invoke your Method as fixtures, too.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def method_instance(request):
    custom_options = request.config.option
    app = "specific tool to test"
    this_instance = Method(app, custom_options)
    return this_instance
```